# How to read Hive table with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I would like to read hive table with Spark. Hive tables data are stored as textFile in `/user/hive/warehouse/problem7.db`.

I do:

```
val warehouseLocation = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse
// Create the Spark Conf and the Spark Session
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Hive").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val table1 = spark.sql("select * from problem7.categories")

table1.show(false)
```

I have the following error:

```
Table or view not found: `problem7`.`categories`
```

Comment: your hive db name is problem7 and table name is categories?

Comment: Run sparkSession.catalog.listTables() to see if your database and table exist.

Comment: @Harshit, yes you are right. db name is problem7 and table name is categories.

Comment: @NirHedvat, I can not find my database problem7 and table categories. But it exist in hive.  The only db and tbl recognized are : cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=src Why ? Should have I to change Spark parameters ?

Comment: What about hive-site.xml? Did you pass it to your application via --files?

Comment: @NirHedvat No I run directly the application on IntelliJ. Maybe should I change un paremeter on hive-site.xml ? spark.sql.warehouse.dir is the same that hive.warehouse.dir ?

Comment: @NirHedvat  I add the following hive.metastore.uris: but it does not work because  of the following error message: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083
metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...                                           val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("File1").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/")
          .set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

Comment: Just to be sure, when you run SHOW TABLES, do you see your table? Just Hive, no Spark.

Comment: yes it works in hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in the following way :

I create a hive-site.xml in spark/conf and add :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

then I start hive metastore service with the following command

```
hive --service metastore
```